# Is there a tool to convert my GWT RemoteServiceServlet into the correct Service and ServiceAsync interfaces?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm working on a GWT project and I find it very tedious to have to add a function to my servlet, then copy and paste the function signature into my Service interface, then copy and paste it into my ServiceAsync interface and change the return parameter to be a callback. Is there a tool or a setting where I can just add public methods to my class and they can get copied into the other interfaces? Even if its not automatic it would be nice to be able to select specific methods and have them copied automatically.

I'm using eclipse and ideally it would update my interface each time I save implementation since thats when it checks my code and complains that my changes break the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the method to your `*Service` interface, then Eclipse can auto-generate the method ("Add unimplemented methods...") in your `*ServiceImpl` servlet, which you can then just fill in. Also, if you've got the [Google Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) installed, it will underline the new method in your `*Service` interface and complain that it's not in the `*ServiceAsync`. It might have a `CTRL + 1` option to generate it in that interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a tool. Just factor out the many RPC methods by just one method that takes a Request/Response. all you need to do is create subclasses of Request/Response and you don't need to think about adding new methods in the 2 interfaces.

You can use Google Guice on the server side to map the incomming request to a class handling the call... or you could use a visitor approach to forward the incoming request to the code handling the request (without resorting on a big instanceof construct).

Answer (score 0):

Instantiations WindowBuilder GWT Designer does exactly what you are looking for.
The RemoteService Wizard will create all three files at the same time as well as keep them in sync as you make changes.

http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/gwtdesigner/index.html

FWIW - I am only a user/purchaser of this product. I am not employed or in any other way related to Instantiations.